# Django 1.11 OuterRef generating invalid Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a model named `Brand` with a field named "name", so this works fine:

```
brands = (Brand
          .objects
          .annotate(as_string=models.functions.Concat('name',models.Value("''"))))
```

I have a model named `Item` with a foreign key to `Brand`. The following does NOT work:

```
annotated_brands = brands.filter(pk=models.OuterRef('brand'))
(Item
 .objects
 .annotate(brand_string=models.Subquery(annotated_brands.values('as_string'))))
```

Specifically, I get a ProgrammingError:

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "policeinventory_item"
LINE 1: ... FROM "PoliceInventory_brand" U0 WHERE U0."id" = (PoliceInve...
```

This is born out when I inspect the SQL query. Here is the broken query:

```
'SELECT "PoliceInventory_item"."id", "PoliceInventory_item"."_created", "PoliceInventory_item"."_created_by_id", "PoliceInventory_item"."_last_updated", "PoliceInventory_item"."_last_updated_by_id", "PoliceInventory_item"."brand_id", "PoliceInventory_item"."type", (SELECT CONCAT(U0."name", \'\') AS "as_string" FROM "PoliceInventory_brand" U0 WHERE U0."id" = (PoliceInventory_item."brand_id") ORDER BY U0."_created" DESC) AS "brand_string" FROM "PoliceInventory_item" ORDER BY "PoliceInventory_item"."_created" DESC'
```

Note how the nested id comparison is performed with `PoliceInventory`, NOT "PoliceInventory" as it is referred to everywhere else.  The following query works as expected:

```
'SELECT "PoliceInventory_item"."id", "PoliceInventory_item"."_created", "PoliceInventory_item"."_created_by_id", "PoliceInventory_item"."_last_updated", "PoliceInventory_item"."_last_updated_by_id", "PoliceInventory_item"."brand_id", "PoliceInventory_item"."type", (SELECT CONCAT(U0."name", \'\') AS "as_string" FROM "PoliceInventory_brand" U0 WHERE U0."id" = ("PoliceInventory_item"."brand_id") ORDER BY U0."_created" DESC) AS "brand_string" FROM "PoliceInventory_item" ORDER BY "PoliceInventory_item"."_created" DESC'
```

The problem seems pretty clearly to be `OuterRef` incorrectly failing to use the same table reference as the outer query, resulting in a mismatch.  Does anyone know how I can persuade `OuterRef` to behave correctly?

Comment: But why is that table `PoliceInventory_item`? do you have a `dbtable` setting in your model?